# Error in Android Programming while connecting to Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing a speech recognition mobile application in android using eclipse IDE. I am getting the following error in my logcat. After connecting PhoneGap only i getting the error. Before that it works good. Please help me to find and rectify the error.

```
12-18 11:20:15.332: W/System(1850): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.anjaneya-1/lib/x86
12-18 11:20:15.367: I/CordovaLog(1850): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
12-18 11:20:15.368: I/CordovaLog(1850): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
12-18 11:20:15.368: D/CordovaLog(1850): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
12-18 11:20:15.368: I/CordovaLog(1850): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
12-18 11:20:15.368: D/CordovaLog(1850): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
12-18 11:20:15.368: D/DroidGap(1850): DroidGap.onCreate()
12-18 11:20:15.371: I/WebViewFactory(1850): Loading com.android.webview version 44.0.2403.119 (code 246011910)
12-18 11:20:15.438: W/System(1850): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/x86
12-18 11:20:16.161: I/LibraryLoader(1850): Time to load native libraries: 205 ms (timestamps 8363-8568)
12-18 11:20:16.187: I/LibraryLoader(1850): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
12-18 11:20:16.304: V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider(1850): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {614f112}
12-18 11:20:16.305: I/LibraryLoader(1850): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
12-18 11:20:16.369: I/chromium(1850): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(120)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
12-18 11:20:16.453: I/BrowserStartupController(1850): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
12-18 11:20:16.476: W/art(1850): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
12-18 11:20:16.535: E/SysUtils(1850): ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
12-18 11:20:17.507: W/chromium(1850): [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)] locale_file_path.empty()
12-18 11:20:17.546: E/libEGL(1850): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
12-18 11:20:17.546: E/libEGL(1850): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
12-18 11:20:17.546: E/chromium(1850): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(327)] No suitable EGL configs found.
12-18 11:20:17.546: E/chromium(1850): [ERROR:gl_surface_android.cc(23)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
12-18 11:20:17.546: E/chromium(1850): [ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(698)] GLSurface::InitializeOneOff failed
12-18 11:20:17.682: W/AudioManagerAndroid(1850): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
12-18 11:20:18.061: E/DataReductionProxySettingListener(1850): No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
12-18 11:20:19.027: W/art(1850): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
12-18 11:20:19.096: W/AwContents(1850): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
12-18 11:20:19.116: D/JsMessageQueue(1850): Set native->JS mode to 2
12-18 11:20:19.116: W/art(1850): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
12-18 11:20:19.116: W/art(1850): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
12-18 11:20:19.117: D/DroidGap(1850): DroidGap.init()
12-18 11:20:19.120: D/CordovaWebView(1850): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
12-18 11:20:19.120: D/PluginManager(1850): init()
12-18 11:20:19.122: D/CordovaWebView(1850): >>> loadUrlNow()
12-18 11:20:19.885: D/DroidGap(1850): Resuming the App
12-18 11:20:19.888: D/DroidGap(1850): Paused the application!
12-18 11:20:19.888: D/CordovaWebView(1850): Handle the pause
12-18 11:20:19.888: I/MainActivity(1850): destroy
12-18 11:20:19.910: W/chromium(1850): [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
12-18 11:20:20.043: I/art(1850): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11719(654KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 51% free, 1178KB/2MB, paused 1.796ms total 153.653ms
12-18 11:20:20.182: D/gralloc_goldfish(1850): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-18 11:20:20.190: I/Choreographer(1850): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-18 11:20:23.025: D/DroidGap(1850): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
12-18 11:20:23.328: D/CordovaLog(1850): exception firing pause event from native
12-18 11:20:23.328: I/chromium(1850): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "exception firing pause event from native", source:  (1)
12-18 11:20:23.478: A/chromium(1850): [FATAL:gl_surface_android.cc(58)] Check failed: kGLImplementationNone != GetGLImplementation() (0 vs. 0)
12-18 11:20:23.478: A/chromium(1850): --------- beginning of crash
12-18 11:20:23.478: A/libc(1850): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1892 (GpuThread)
12-18 11:23:30.459: W/System(2116): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.anjaneya-1/lib/x86
12-18 11:23:31.121: I/CordovaLog(2116): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
12-18 11:23:31.121: I/CordovaLog(2116): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
12-18 11:23:31.121: D/CordovaLog(2116): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
12-18 11:23:31.121: I/CordovaLog(2116): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
12-18 11:23:31.121: D/CordovaLog(2116): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
12-18 11:23:31.121: D/DroidGap(2116): DroidGap.onCreate()
12-18 11:23:31.132: I/WebViewFactory(2116): Loading com.android.webview version 44.0.2403.119 (code 246011910)
12-18 11:23:31.170: W/System(2116): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/x86
12-18 11:23:31.175: I/LibraryLoader(2116): Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 3580-3582)
12-18 11:23:31.175: I/LibraryLoader(2116): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
12-18 11:23:31.242: V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider(2116): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {614f112}
12-18 11:23:31.242: I/LibraryLoader(2116): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
12-18 11:23:31.242: I/chromium(2116): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(120)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
12-18 11:23:31.298: I/BrowserStartupController(2116): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
12-18 11:23:31.299: W/art(2116): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
12-18 11:23:31.300: E/SysUtils(2116): ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
12-18 11:23:31.362: W/chromium(2116): [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)] locale_file_path.empty()
12-18 11:23:31.364: E/libEGL(2116): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
12-18 11:23:31.364: E/libEGL(2116): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
12-18 11:23:31.364: E/chromium(2116): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(327)] No suitable EGL configs found.
12-18 11:23:31.364: E/chromium(2116): [ERROR:gl_surface_android.cc(23)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
12-18 11:23:31.364: E/chromium(2116): [ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(698)] GLSurface::InitializeOneOff failed
12-18 11:23:31.385: E/DataReductionProxySettingListener(2116): No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
12-18 11:23:31.458: W/AudioManagerAndroid(2116): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
12-18 11:23:31.470: W/art(2116): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
12-18 11:23:31.475: W/AwContents(2116): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
12-18 11:23:31.483: D/JsMessageQueue(2116): Set native->JS mode to 2
12-18 11:23:31.483: W/art(2116): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
12-18 11:23:31.483: W/art(2116): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
12-18 11:23:31.484: D/DroidGap(2116): DroidGap.init()
12-18 11:23:31.505: D/CordovaWebView(2116): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
12-18 11:23:31.505: D/PluginManager(2116): init()
12-18 11:23:31.514: D/CordovaWebView(2116): >>> loadUrlNow()
12-18 11:23:31.642: D/DroidGap(2116): Resuming the App
12-18 11:23:31.670: W/chromium(2116): [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
12-18 11:23:31.688: I/art(2116): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12550(687KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 52% free, 1164KB/2MB, paused 2.144ms total 230.435ms
12-18 11:23:31.742: D/gralloc_goldfish(2116): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-18 11:23:32.229: I/Choreographer(2116): Skipped 123 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-18 11:23:32.274: D/DroidGap(2116): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
12-18 11:23:32.284: A/chromium(2116): [FATAL:gl_surface_android.cc(58)] Check failed: kGLImplementationNone != GetGLImplementation() (0 vs. 0)
12-18 11:23:32.285: A/libc(2116): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2155 (GpuThread)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is almost exactly the same error as [Cordova 6.0.0 Unfortunaly, HelloWorld has stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36042390/5276890). It seems to be related to [this bug from ionic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-app-crashing-only-on-android-emulator/33375.).

According to them, "switching from Snapshot to Host GPU solved this problem."

This makes sense as three of the last errors are related to opengl.

*Note to various moderators: I tried to close one as a duplicate of the other, but that can't be done because there's no answer. Tried looking on meta for 'duplicate unanswered' but they simply say not to do it. I figure I'll post a possible answer and if either one is accepted, I'll close the other as a dup.*