# Cordova 6.0.0 Unfortunaly, HelloWorld has stopped

Tags: android, cordova

I try to use cordova in windows for create a simple android app. I create the first project using command `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`

I add the Android platform, I try to build and build success, but when I emulate the app don't start and receive the error on screen:

> Unfortunaly, HelloWorld has stopped.

logcat:

```
  03-16 16:44:19.073    2442-2442/com.example.hello W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.hello-1/lib/x86
03-16 16:44:19.266    2442-2442/com.example.hello I/WebViewFactory﹕ Loading com.android.webview version 44.0.2403.119 (code 246011910)
03-16 16:44:19.310    2442-2442/com.example.hello W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/x86
03-16 16:44:19.377    2442-2442/com.example.hello I/LibraryLoader﹕ Time to load native libraries: 62 ms (timestamps 9389-9451)
03-16 16:44:19.377    2442-2442/com.example.hello I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
03-16 16:44:19.392    2442-2442/com.example.hello I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
03-16 16:44:19.392    2442-2442/com.example.hello I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(120)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
03-16 16:44:19.483    2442-2442/com.example.hello I/BrowserStartupController﹕ Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
03-16 16:44:19.484    2442-2442/com.example.hello W/art﹕ Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
03-16 16:44:19.486    2442-2442/com.example.hello E/SysUtils﹕ ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
03-16 16:44:19.568    2442-2442/com.example.hello W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)] locale_file_path.empty()
03-16 16:44:19.571    2442-2442/com.example.hello E/libEGL﹕ validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
03-16 16:44:19.571    2442-2442/com.example.hello E/libEGL﹕ validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
03-16 16:44:19.571    2442-2442/com.example.hello E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(327)] No suitable EGL configs found.
03-16 16:44:19.571    2442-2442/com.example.hello E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_android.cc(23)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
03-16 16:44:19.571    2442-2442/com.example.hello E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(698)] GLSurface::InitializeOneOff failed
03-16 16:44:19.628    2442-2468/com.example.hello W/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ Requires BLUETOOTH permission
03-16 16:44:19.667    2442-2442/com.example.hello E/DataReductionProxySettingListener﹕ No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
03-16 16:44:19.757    2442-2442/com.example.hello W/art﹕ Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
03-16 16:44:19.762    2442-2442/com.example.hello W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
03-16 16:44:20.182    2442-2442/com.example.hello D/SystemWebViewEngine﹕ CordovaWebView is running on device made by: unknown
03-16 16:44:20.188    2442-2442/com.example.hello W/art﹕ Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
03-16 16:44:20.188    2442-2442/com.example.hello W/art﹕ Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
03-16 16:44:20.246    2442-2452/com.example.hello I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7609(505KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 64% free, 861KB/2MB, paused 1.373ms total 448.240ms
03-16 16:44:20.310    2442-2466/com.example.hello W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
03-16 16:44:20.368    2442-2442/com.example.hello D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without host-side GPU emulation detected.
03-16 16:44:20.376    2442-2442/com.example.hello W/art﹕ Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
03-16 16:44:20.410    2442-2442/com.example.hello W/art﹕ Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
03-16 16:44:20.586    2442-2452/com.example.hello I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1447(97KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(2MB) LOS objects, 35% free, 926KB/1438KB, paused 2.668ms total 209.255ms
03-16 16:44:20.587    2442-2480/com.example.hello A/chromium﹕ [FATAL:gl_surface_android.cc(58)] Check failed: kGLImplementationNone != GetGLImplementation() (0 vs. 0)
03-16 16:44:20.587    2442-2480/com.example.hello A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2480 (GpuThread)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in Android Programming while connecting to Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349353/error-in-android-programming-while-connecting-to-phonegap)

Answer (score 0):

This is almost exactly the same error as [Error in Android Programming while connecting to Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34349353/5276890). It seems to be related to [this bug from ionic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-app-crashing-only-on-android-emulator/33375.).

According to them, "switching from Snapshot to Host GPU solved this problem."

This makes sense as three of the last errors are related to opengl.

*Note to various moderators: I tried to close one as a duplicate of the other, but that can't be done because there's no answer. Tried looking on meta for 'duplicate unanswered' but they simply say not to do it. I figure I'll post a possible answer and if either one is accepted, I'll close the other as a dup.*